# App to access file system and run in browser

Tags: javascript, electron, portable-applications

I am willing to make a portable app using HTML CSS JS and similar languages that doesn't need any installation and can be accessed via a browser.
The app should be able to access the file system and create, write and delete files.
The required files will be on the local machine.
I have tried
Applets but the performance is too inconsistent and depends on browsers.
I have also tried using electron but the end result needs installation (correct me if I am wrong)
I am open to all suggestions

Comment: portable in terms of what? cross-browser?

Comment: "The app should be able to access the file system" Local file system ? Browser are sandboxed, and as far as I know cannot access the local file system from their sandboxed javascript environment.

Comment: portable in sense if I place files anywhere in the system it should be able to run it o a browser

Answer (score 0):

Electron's apps can be portable. Copy the electron build resulted folder into a pendrive and execute the main .exe file from there. Everything should work

Comment: He wants an app that "can be accessed via a browser". Not an executable

Comment: if I place the electron build files/folder on a shared network drive and access through windows will it work??